# SMB settings in Windows 2016 VM

Tags: windows, network-adapter, smb

I am having trouble about advanced settings of network interface to get more speed.
If RSS is enabled;
Sending: 40MB/s
Receiving: 40MB/s

If RSS is disabled;
Sending: 70MB/s
Receiving: 10MB/s

I can give all the details about my system..

Comment: More details needed. Are you using Hyper-V with generation 2 VM?

Comment: It is a VM in VMware host. I wonder if it is possible to reach 70MB/s for both TX and RX somehow.

Answer (score 0):

There is only so much that you can do with a VM whose hardware is emulated,
so that the operating system in the VM is in effect optimizing non-existent
hardware.

Some actions you may take:

- Set the disk of the VM to SCSI emulation
- Increase the VM memory, to allow for more operating system caching
- Check swap statistics in the guest operating system to verify that it has adequate memory
- Defragment the file systems on the VM
- Disable antivirus scans on the VMDK and VMEM files
- Separate the VM's physical disk drive from the drive with the system page file
- If sizable RAM is available, disable memory trimming by adding the line
  `MemTrimRate=0` to the virtual machine's `.VMX` file
- Use the most current VMWare version and VMWare Tools in the VM.

If the performance is still insufficient, for Windows host and guest,
using Hyper-V will be more efficient.
[Hyper-V Generation 2](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/dn282285%28v%3Dws.11%29)
Windows guests have better integration with the disk driver of the Windows
host.

Comment: By the way, I have to give you another important detail; If I open second file explorer with different destination ip address and start second coppying, I get x2 speed. I mean; 1. When copying one file from local drive to one mapped drive, speed is 40MB/s, 2. When copying one file from local drive to two different mapped drives (mapped using different IP add.) at the same time, total speed is 80MB/s (40MB/s each), 3. When copying one file from local drive to two different mapped drives (mapped using same destination IP add.) at the same time, total speed is 40MB/s (20MB/s each)

Comment: Seems to be a per-connection or per-explorer-instance limit. As explorer is the slowest copier around, try maybe other alternative copying methods as test.

Answer (score 0):

By the way, I have to give you another important detail;
If I open second file explorer with different destination ip address and start second coppying, I get x2 speed.
I mean;
1. When copying one file from local drive to one mapped drive, speed is 40MB/s,
2. When copying one file from local drive to two different mapped drives (mapped using **different IP add.**) at the same time, total speed is 80MB/s (40MB/s each),
3. When copying one file from local drive to two different mapped drives (mapped using **same destination IP add.**) at the same time, total speed is 40MB/s (20MB/s each)
How can it be possible to get 80MB/s when copying one file to one mapped drive at a time??